# Developer Story: timeline sorting for projects not working

Tags: bug, developer-story

Just added two projects (with release dates) but they show up in the wrong place in the timeline. I think an image will suffice, see below:

[image: developer story timeline]

Comment: Do you mean the "Great DJ!" and "typr.club" items? They look in the correct order to me. What should the correct order be?